# Ambari API on HDInsight returns 404

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, ambari

I am trying out some basics on Ambari APIs on an HDInsight cluster. The following requests all return a 404 (Tried both using a browser as well as a REST client)

```
https://mynewclusterabcd.azurehdinsight.net/ambari/api/v1/clusters
https://mynewclusterabcd.azurehdinsight.net/ambari/api/v1/clusters/mynewclusterabcd/hosts
https://mynewclusterabcd.azurehdinsight.net/ambari/api/v1/clusters/mynewclusterabcd/services
```

whereas I am able to get to the Ambari cluster dashboard using the following URL, with the same credentials.

```
https://mynewclusterabcd.azurehdinsight.net
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. There is no requirement of keyword 'ambari' within the URLs for the new version of the clusters (3.6).

This documentation was the root of the problem since it does not mention the same:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/hdinsight/hdinsight-monitor-use-ambari-api.md

The following requests work:

```
https://mynewclusterabcd.azurehdinsight.net/api/v1/clusters
https://mynewclusterabcd.azurehdinsight.net/api/v1/clusters/mynewclusterabcd/hosts
https://mynewclusterabcd.azurehdinsight.net/api/v1/clusters/mynewclusterabcd/services
```